# CCSprite userObject has unexpected null value (cocos2d 3.2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to save an NSNumber object as the userObject property of a CCSprite but this value is changing to null for some reason that I cannot figure out. The CCSprite is created in the init method for my custom CCNode:

```
@implementation MainScene {
    NSMutableArray *sprites;
    NSArray *imageFileNames;
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        int spriteCount = 9;

        imageFileNames = @[@"ccbResources/clubs.png", @"ccbResources/cog.png", @"ccbResources/diamonds.png", @"ccbResources/dice.png", @"ccbResources/droplet.png", @"ccbResources/heart.png", @"ccbResources/pacman.png", @"ccbResources/pawn.png", @"ccbResources/spades.png"];

        sprites = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:spriteCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < spriteCount; i++) {            
            CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:imageFileNames[i%imageFileNames.count]];
            [self addChild:sprite];
            sprite.scale = 1.8f;
            sprite.position = ccp(xPos, yPos);
            sprite.color = [CCColor colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0f green:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0f blue:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0f];
            sprite.userObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];

            [sprites addObject:sprite];

            CCLog(@"%@", sprite.userObject); // outputs the value of i, as intended
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

At the end of the init method, when I print out the value of sprite.userObject, it is equal to i so the NSNumber is successfully retained as the userObject property of the sprite.

But during the update method, the value becomes null for some reason:

```
-(void) update:(CCTime)delta {
    for (CCSprite *sprite in sprites) {
        CCLog(@"%@", sprite.userObject);
        // outputs "(null)" on the first update,
        // and outputs the value of newSpriteType on subsequent updates

        int newSpriteType = arc4random_uniform( (u_int32_t)imageFileNames.count );
        sprite.userObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt:newSpriteType];
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why the value of `sprite.userObject` is always null when update is called for the first time, and remains null until a new `NSNumber` is assigned to it within the `update` method. This is especially confusing because `sprite.userObject` has a valid `NSNumber` assigned to it in the `init` method and this value is not changed or even read at any point other than inside the `update` method.

Comment: Odd. Try assigning the sprite itself to the userObject to see if this changes the first update behavior. If it does, check if userObject is declared as weak property. If so that ought to be changed. Another thing to try is to loop over self.children in update rather than the sprites array to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Also log the sprite instances on init and update, then compare their pointer values to ensure they are the same sprite instances.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I went over your suggestions and found no difference in the behaviour of the app (values are set correctly in init, but null in update) and checked that userObject is indeed a strong property. So I set a symbolic breakpoint on `-[CCNode setUserObject:]` and have found that `-[CCBReader cleanUpNodeGraph:]` is being called and that is where the userObject property is being explicitly set to null.

Comment: interesting, in that case move the init code to didLoadFromCCB

Comment: Yes that fixed it. SpriteBuilder should really auto-add an implementation (perhaps a commented out one) to the source file of the nodes it creates. I wasn't aware of this because I haven't used SpriteBuilder before and only started now because it is the preferred workflow for cocos2d projects.

Comment: in the future this will both be better documented and available as autocomplete in code, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153721/where-does-the-method-didloadfromccb-come-from-in-cocos2d-v3 and https://github.com/spritebuilder/SpriteBuilder/issues/613